# Is libvlc in Java complete as libvlc in C?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, vlc, libvlc, vlc-android

I want to develop an Android program on Android platform,and I also compile some libs(eg. libvlc.so,libvlcjni.so……). 
But after I built these libs,I also find some Java codes,a package named libvlc,which is written in Java. I've read some of the APIs the videolan.org provides,and also read some of the java edition codes.
Now I hava a question,if I just use the Java api,is it enough?(Firstly,I just want develop a simple player).Or is it not complete as the C library? If not,can anybody tell me the main difference?
I live in a country where we don't speak English,perhaps my English is poor.Hoping that you can get my idea.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libvlc is written in C. To be able to use it on Android with Java, you need a JNI wrapper like https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-android/tree/master/libvlc/jni.

Have a look at those official android samples https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libvlc-android-samples

Comment: tks.I've found the solution.